# Why is this custom view attribute ignored?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-attributes

I am trying to define an attribute for any view using the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html), as explained in [this Android Developers post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Pq6aDpZEYA5).

To do so, the post says one first needs a layout with an enclosing `<layout>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:attribute='@{"name"}'/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

At this point, [the layout caused a `ClassNotFoundException` when inflated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081859/why-does-using-the-binding-interface-resut-in-a-classnotfound-exception). The only way I found to get rid of it was to add a `<data></data>` node, even if it was absent from the Android Developers post:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data></data>
    ...
</layout>
```

(The post does not mention it, but I had to enable `dataBinding` in my `build.gradle` as recommended in the [Guide](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html) before I could build.)

The post then explains how to write a `BindingAdapter` method to process the attribute:

```
import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class AttributesBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("bind:attribute")
    public static void bindAttribute(View view, String attributeName){
        Log.e("PLN", attributeName);
    }
}
```

However, the `bindAttribute` method is never called. I do see the generated code for the layout in my build folder, but nothing else happens.

#### Why is my BindingAdapter ignored?

Comment: It should be `@BindingAdapter("bind:attribute")` instead of `@BindingAdapter("app:attribute")` , you should refer [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html#attribute_setters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I was not creating the Binding correctly:

Following the first steps of the [Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), I used `DataBindingUtil.setContentView`, but for `ListView` items you need to use `ItemBinding.inflate` in the `Adapter`'s `ViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                    R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding.getRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell in that first link, the `data` tag is present. It was probably omitted in the G+ post because its boilerplate. In fact, in the docs it says

> Data-binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of layout followed by a data element and a view root element.

Anyways, I think you might be missing some required sugar in the layout file. Can you try:

```
app:attribute='@{"name"}`
```

Maybe its required for the binding to occur. I mean right now I am aiming blind until I actually test this. But from that post I see `app:imageUrl='@{"http://example.com/image.jpg"}'`.

Comment: I agree with you that one should follow the guide and use this data tag, which I did. Still, the problem persists.

As for the post you linked, how do you think it could help? The OP has a compile-time error (whereas my app builds and runs but ignores my BindingAdapter), and the accepted solution using `@BindingMethods(@BindingMethod(...))` instead of `@BindingAdapter` still results in the method not being called. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @PLNech that link I added should be gone. I misunderstood the problem. Adding the `@{}` didn't help? Maybe try adding it exactly as it is in the post. so `app:attribute='@{"name"}'`.

Comment: You are probably right about the syntax (and I updated the question to reflect it). However, even with `app:attribute='@{"name"}'` the method is still not called...

Comment: @PLNech what is your layout file called?

Comment: `item.xml`(it will be used to display items in a `ListView`)

Comment: Is it possible you aren't using the convention? ` the layout file contact_item.xml will generate ContactItemBinding`. If its not being called its possible that it can't find it since it might expect it in a specific file.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `@BindingAdapter("bind:attribute")` instead of `@BindingAdapter("app:attribute")`

and try with this, it might work.

```
app:attribute="@{`name`}"
```